# wpf Excel how to open a excel file inside a window

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, xaml, automation

I'm using WPFand I want to open an excel file inside my window, I wanna clic in a cell of the excel sheet and get by code the name of the cell , like "A21" is it I guess that is posible with  automation but I can't find an example

Any help will be great, 
thanks in advance

Comment: Your only need is to get the cell address? Because I think you could load the Excel data in a DataGrid, select the cell you want and get the equivalent Excel cell address.

Comment: the problem is that I don't know the format of the sheet and the possition of the data that I'm looking for, I need to search visually the data and get the cell name by clicking it and saving the name (ej. A21, B15,.. etc) in a textbox, this is the first step, the second step is to open the excel by code and get the data in the cell

Comment: For what you're describing, if you only need to get the content of the cell visually, you could just read the entire file and load into a DataGrid (the second row third column would be equivalent to cell C2, for example). Then, you select visually the cell you want, so you could get the data directly, or if you want the address, just pick the row and column numbers